# How to make bottom top layer of website transparent to background slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Ok so I have a function that slideshow a background in the background of the site . I want the Navigation Links to be transparent and the body to be transparent. Not transparent as in no color , transparent as in you can see the slideshows in the background.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
function test() {
    var count = $("img").size();
    $("#background_images img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        if (!--count)
            $(this).delay(10000 * index).fadeIn(3000).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000, function() { test(); });
        else
            $(this).delay(10000 * index).fadeIn(3000).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
test();
});

-->
</script>
<style>
body, html{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  filter: alpha (opacity=50);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html { overflow: hidden; filter: alpha (opacity=50); }
body { overflow: auto; filter: alpha (opacity=50);}

#background_images img{
position: absolute;
top:0;
display:none;
width: 99%;
z-index: 1;
}

#container { width: 1000px; background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; border-left: 1px solid         #000; border-right: 1px solid #000; position: relative; z-index: 2; }
#header { width: inherit; height: 0px; background: url(../images/header.png) no-repeat; }
#navbar { width: inherit; height: 35px; background: url(../images/navbar.png) repeat-x;    border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; }

/* navbar ul content */

#navbar ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0;  margin: 0; }
#navbar li { display: inline; float: left; padding-left: 15px; margin: 0; }
#navbar li a { display: block; width: 50px; height: 26px; padding: 5px; color: #000;  text-decoration: none; text-align: center; }
#navbar li a:hover { background: #fff; color: #666; }

#content { width: inherit; background: url(../images/shadow.png) repeat-x top #fff; }

/* content div's "cont" class */

#content .cont { padding: 50px; }

#footer { width: inherit; height: 150px; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:.40;
opacity:.40;
text-align: center; padding-top: 100% }

/* footer div's "cont" class */

#footer .cont { padding: 5px; }

#footer .footlinks a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='background_images'><img src='ocean.jpg' /><img src='sky.jpg' /></div>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">

    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="navbar">       
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
    <li>
           <a href="#">
              <img src="../ArtemaDeuzz/navigationImages/pic2.png" alt=""/>
          <span class="sdt_active"></span>
          <span class="sdt_wrap">
            <span class="sdt_link">Collections</span>
            <span class="sdt_descr">Our work</span>
          </span>
            </a>
            <div class="sdt_box">
          <a href="#">Formal</a>
          <a href="#">Indigenous</a>
          <a href="#">Vintage</a>
                      <a href="#">Retro</a>
                      <a href="#">Modern</a>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../ArtemaDeuzz/navigationImages/pic3.png" alt=""/>
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
          <span class="sdt_link">Entice Ur Match</span>
          <span class="sdt_descr">Customize Your Own.</span>
        </span>
       </a>
        </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="../ArtemaDeuzz/navigationImages/pic4.png" alt=""/>
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
          <span class="sdt_link">Be A Designer</span>
          <span class="sdt_descr">Up For A Challenge</span>
        </span>
      </a>
</li>
            <li>
            <div id="center">
                <a href="#" id="popUpAbout">
                    <script>

                    </script>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Who Are We</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Matt & Na'il</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div><!-- #navbar -->

    <div id="content">
        <div class="cont">
        </div><!-- #content .cont -->
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="cont">
            <p>&copy; 2012. All Rights Reserved. Designed by Matthew Harding. &copy;</p>
            <p class="footlinks"><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">Test</a> | <a href="#">Test</a> | <a href="#">Test</a> | <a href="#">Test</a></p> 

        </div><!-- #footer .cont -->
    </div><!-- #footer -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: You haven't posted anything from your HTML structure. You already used opacity in your CSS. This would have been my suggestion. Please post your (simplified) HTML structure

Comment: wait can you not see the HTML ?

Comment: im trying opacity but it wont work . Im starting to think its not possible

Comment: I see only a script and a style tag.

Comment: alright it should be good now

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, have you tried rgba, [Look Here](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) example:

```
div {
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}
```

the last parameter is the opacity value.

I can't try all your code but look at this test, you can start with this base and do all the other changes you need, its working for the base of your html and with opacity working, you only have to see why in the rest of your code is making it change.

```
body, html{
    background-color:#ffaadd;
      width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#background_images
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid green;
  background-color:#aaffdd;
    position:absolute;
}

#content
{    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#navbar{
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.3); 
}

#footer { width: inherit; height: 150px; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:.40;
opacity:.40;
text-align: center; padding-top: 100% }

/* footer div's "cont" class */

#footer .cont { padding: 5px; }

#footer .footlinks a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
```

Look how its working [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eA7Nc/)

Comment: yes that is actually what I am trying to do , but it isn't quite working for me when I do it .